# Rails 3 radio button values from a mapped array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

UPDATE: THE CODE IN THIS POST HAS BEEN CHANGED TO THE WORKING SOLUTION.

To make radio buttons display stored values from a mapped array.

Controller:

```
@questions = Question.all
@ans = Answer.where(user_id = current_user.id)
@answers = @questions.map { |q| [q, @ans.find_by_question_id(q.id)] }
```

View:

```
<% @answers.each do |q| %>
    <%= q[0].question %> [<%= q[1].id %>] <%= q[1].score %> 
    <% [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].each do |f| %>
        <%= radio_button_tag q[0].name, f, f == q[1].score %>
    <% end %>
    <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: @dmarkow, @MatteoAlessani, @Zabba, @McStretch hoping you might take a stab at this. Thanks if you can.

Comment: @corroded you asked a rails / radio_button question... wondering if you could take a stab at this.

Comment: @AnApprentice, you asked a similar question, could you take a stab at it?

Comment: @Skilldrick you answered this kind of question before, can you give this one a go? Thanks.

Comment: @Jay, what is going wrong with the view code you originally posted? Are the radio buttons not being generated at all, or with the wrong `f`?

Comment: @McStretch, it is generating the buttons but none of them are checked. I already have test data in the database so there should be values that should generate a checked button for all questions. Thanks, K!

Comment: @Jay, you might want to throw a `<%= debug q[1].score %>` above your radio_button_tag declaration to see if any of the scores are giving you truthy values. If they're all `nil` or `false` then that's your problem. Or if they're all true, then you probably have `checked="checked"` for all of the radio buttons in the group, which isn't possible. In fact, the name 'score' is the same for all of the radio buttons, which means all radio buttons are all a part of the same group. You should define it with something like this: `<%= radio_button_tag "score-#{some_specific_id}", f, q[1].score %>`

Comment: With the new name definition, the different `radio_button_tag`s for different questions will have separate radio button groups, which is what you want I believe. Let me know if any of this helps or answers the question, and I can add an answer for you to accept and close this guy out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, folks. Thanks for your help. Mike, you were close. There were two problems. First, the name "score" would be assigned to every button for every question. The name needs to be the same for every button for one question, but needs to change on the next question. See q[0].name below. Second, the score is numerical, not a string. So "to_s" resulted in every button being checked as it was made. Since there could only be one button checked per set, checking every button resulted in the last button being checked for each set. (e.g. the score 5 being checked each time)

```
<% @answers.each do |q| %>
    <%= q[0].question %> [<%= q[1].id %>] <%= q[1].score %> 
    <% [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].each do |f| %>
        <%= radio_button_tag q[0].name, f, f == q[1].score %>
    <% end %>
    <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey @Jay, don't forget to mark this answer as the correct one. It's okay to mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: Indeed. I'm still learning myself. Glad to see you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

edit: oops... forgot the @ on answers.each. fixed

```
<% @answers.each do |q| %>
  <%= q[0].question %>
  <% [1..5].each do |f| %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'score', f, (f == q[1].score).to_s %>
  <% end %>
  <br />
<% end %>
```

Its off the top of my head but basically you have to pass true or false not the number checked. I'm assuming that q[1].score is a number from 1 to 5

Comment: so far this solution and variations of it are not working. But thanks for trying :=]

Comment: since you laid the foundation, i decided to credit you with the answer. Thanks.